# Pairing between cohomology and the image of the Hurewicz homomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, homology

Let $X$ be a compact manifold of dimension $\geq k$. Denote by
\begin{equation}
h: \pi _k(X) \rightarrow H_k(X,\mathbb{Z})
\end{equation}
be Hurewicz homomorphism and by $\Gamma _k(X)\subset H_k(X,\mathbb{Z})$ its image. I want to look at the pairing
\begin{equation}
\langle \ . \ ,\ . \ \rangle : \ \Gamma _k(X)_{\text{free}} \times H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})_{\text{free}}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
obtained by restricting the the Kronecker pairing between the free subgroups of homology and cohomology, which is non-degenerate. In general the restriction above will be degenerate. Indeed given a non-vanishing class $\omega \in H^k (X,\mathbb{Z})_{\text{free}}$, it is possible that for any $f: S^k \rightarrow X$ the pull-back $f^* \omega$ is zero. I'm looking for some cases in which I can say something more on this degeneracy.

In particular if $\omega \in H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})_{\text{free}}$ is also a generator of the cohomology ring (so that it cannot be written as the product of two classes of lower degree) I have some intuition that maybe $\langle \Sigma , \omega \rangle \neq 0$ for at least one $\Sigma \in \Gamma _k (X)$. I am not sure whether this is true, and if it is how to prove it. Or if it is false how to modify a bit statement to get some true fact connecting the generators of the cohomology ring with the image of the Hurewicz map. Can somebody say something about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact"?  Do you have in mind De Rham cohomology or something like that?  But in that case, the coefficients are not in Z.

Comment: @user43326 I think exact $=0$ here.

Comment: I’m on mobile, but I would look at manifolds that approximate eilenberg maclanespaces in homotopy to find counter examples.

Comment: @user43326 by exact I meant zero in cohomology.

Comment: @ThomasRot I would like to see a finite dimensional counterexample, if you find it I would be glad to see the datails.

Comment: Your question seems to be related to Theorem 15.11 in Felix-Halperin-Thomas's book on rational homotopy theory. If $X$ is simply connected and of finite type (e.g. a compact manifold), then there exists a commutative differential graded algebra generated by $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_\bullet(X);\mathbb Q)$ (and satisfying some additional constraints) whose cohomology is $H^\bullet(X;\mathbb Q)$. So I believe that counterexamples to your conjecture will not be simply connected (in fact, not even nilpotent spaces).

Comment: @SebastianGoette Well, it's not true that cohomology of a nilmanifold is generated in degree 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, by the existence of nontrivial Massey products.

Call a cohomology class decomposable if it is in the subgroup generated by cup products of pairs of classes of positive dimension.

As you say, any decomposable class pairs to zero with all spherical homology classes (i.e. those in the image of the Hurewicz map). That's because in the cohomology of a sphere all decomposable classes are zero.

But more generally in the cohomology of a sphere the Massey product of three positive-degree cohomology classes is always zero, and this implies that in general the Massey product of three positive-degree cohomology classes (when it is defined) must pair to zero with all spherical classes.

Here the Massey product of $a\in H^i(X)$, $b\in H^j(X)$, and $c\in H^k(X)$ is defined when $a\cup b=0$ and $b\cup c=0$, and it belongs to the quotient of $H^{i+j+k+1}(X)$ by its decomposable part. So any Massey product that is non-zero (in that quotient) gives us a cohomology class that is not decomposable but does pair to zero with spherical homology classes.

Answer (score 3):

i think that nothing even close to this statement can be true. There is an example I know off the top of my head; although Hurewitz in my example vanishes (because manifold will be aspherical), I'm unsure in which way one may impose conditions which can prevent you from taking something like a connected sum — or some other surgery — in order to "artificially add" a piece where Hurewicz does not vanish.

Manifold I'm looking at is quotient of Heisenberg group by integral lattice, so it is a classifying space of integral Heisenberg group $Q_n$; this lattice is a central extension of $\Bbb Z\langle x_i, y_i \rangle = \Bbb Z^{2n}$ by $\Bbb Z\langle\eta\rangle$ with usual symplectic form by a cocycle that tells you that commutator of two elements is equal to the value of that symplectic form in central $\Bbb Z\langle\eta\rangle$.

There's DGA model of this manifold, given by $\Lambda(x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n, z)$, where all generators are in degree 1, all $x, y$ are cycles, and $dz = \omega$, where $\omega = x_1 \wedge y_1 + \dots + x_n \wedge y_n$.

Quick calculation shows that $H^s(Q_n, \Bbb Q)$ is *almost* equal to $\frac {\wedge^s(x_i, y_i)}{\wedge^{s-2}(x_i, y_i) \wedge \omega}$, but this falls short at $s = n + 1$; there will be an additional 1-dimensional piece generated by $\alpha z$, where $\alpha$ is in annulator of $\omega$ taken as an element of (usual, non-graded) exterior algebra. It's easy to see that this element is indecomposable.

As our manifold was aspherical, there's nothing to pair it with.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, just an extended version of my comment above. Something related to your conjecture holds in rational homotopy theory, at least for a class of compact manifolds including the simply connected ones. However, the pairing does not involve indecomposables in the cohomology ring, but indecomposables in a minimal Sullivan model. Both spaces of indecomposables share a common subspace, and the two pairings agree on it. I would be glad if some expert in rational homotopy theory who reads this adds some missing details.

Each connected topological space $X$ has a minimal Sullivan model $(V,d)$. It consists of a graded and filtered $\mathbb Q$-vector space
$$V=\bigcup_{k\ge 0} V(k)\text{ with }V(0)\subset V(1)\subset\dots$$
and a linear map $d\colon V\to\Lambda V$, where $\Lambda V$ is the free graded commutative algebra generated by $V$, satisfying
$$d|_{V(0)}=0\text{ and }d|_{V(k)}\colon V(k)\to\Lambda V(k-1)\cap\Lambda^+V\cdot\Lambda^+V\text{ for }k\ge1\;,$$
such that $(\Lambda V,d)$ is quasiisomorphic to a certain natural differential graded algebra that computes $H^\bullet(X;\mathbb Q)$.
In particular, $\mathrm{im}d$ does not hit $V\subset\Lambda V$ itself, so $\ker d|_V$ is a subspace of $H^\bullet(X;\mathbb Q)$ consisting of indecomposable elements.

Theorem 15.11 in Felix-Halperin-Thomas's book [Rational Homotopy Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-0105-9) says that if $X$ is simply connected and of finite type (e.g. a compact manifold), there is nondegenerate natural pairing
$$V\times(\pi_\bullet(X)\otimes\mathbb Q)\to\mathbb Q\;.$$
This allows you to find a subspace $\ker(d|_V)\subset H^\bullet(X;\mathbb Q)$
isomorphic to $(\Gamma(X)\otimes\mathbb Q)^*$.

As an example take $S^{2n}$. Here, $V$ has a basis $a$, $b$ with $a\in V^{2n}(0)$, $b\in V^{4n-1}(1)$ such that $da=0$ and $db=a^2$.
The rational homotopy groups of $S^{2n}$ are $\mathbb Q$ in degrees $2n$ and $4n-1$
and $0$ otherwise.
Note that $b$ pairs nontrivially with a class that vanishes under the Hurewicz map.

Finally, Denis T's counterexample exhibits an indecomposable element in $H^\bullet(\Lambda V,d)$ that has a representative in $\Lambda^{\ge 2}V$.

Comment: ...Well, there's only one problem — pairing between indecomposables in cohomology and rational homotopy has nothing to do with Kronecker pairing, or with cohomology classes pulling back nontrivially to some spheroid.

Comment: Aren't you exaggerating here? $\alpha\in\pi_k(X)$ induces a class of pullback maps $\Lambda V_X\to\Lambda V_k$ ($V_k$ is a Sullivan model for $S^k$ here), which have a well-defined "linear part" $Q(\alpha)\colon V_X\to V_k$. Pairing with $\alpha$ means $\langle Q(\alpha)a,[S^k]\rangle$ for  $a\in V_X^k$, see [FHT, sect 13(c)]. So if $a\in V^k\cap\ker d$, then the pairing ultimately boils down to the one coming from Kronecker and Hurewicz. On the other hand, if $a\not\in\ker d$, the pairing has no cohomological meaning.

Comment: @DenisT What you probably meant to say is that $H^\bullet(\Lambda V,d)$ can contain indecomposable elements that do not come from $V$. At least this happens in your counterexample above.